# How to perform Partial execution in HP ALM using PAF?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am doing PAF automation of HP-ALM using tags. I want to perform partial execution execution in HP ALM. Is it possible to handle the setup at the flow level and as well as activity level?

Answer (score 0):

- This feature helps the user to partially execute the PAF scripts in HP ALM.
- To enable the partial execution attributes needs to be setup in your flow and activity files.  **manual = “true”** in activity
- In the activity, include the attribute manual=”true” for the steps not required to be executed in HP ALM or the steps that need to be executed manually before syncing to HP ALM.

**Syntax**

```
<tag attribute=”” manual="true"></tag>
```